# How to exclude weekends when adding days in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables on oracle DB
PRB_phases which contains:
PRBID,CREATION_DATE,INSERTIONDATE,ENDDATE,PRIORITY,COMPLEXITY,PHASES
and table RFQ_HOLD_TIME which contains 
RFQID,HOLDDATE,UNHOLDDATE where i save the time that the problem is on hold status
so on the following query except the information about the problem also calculate the result of holdtime and add it to the "phase"deadline but i want to exclude the weekend when add days for deadline phases an also when add time to deadline from the holdtime.

the query is the following and it works the only thing that i want help is to exclude the weekends:

```
select  PRBID,CREATION_DATE,CURRENT_PHASES,NEXT_PHASES,CLASSIFICATION_DEADLINE,FEASIBILITY_DEADLINE,
CASE          
            WHEN HUGE.CURRENT_PHASES = 'Classification'  and to_date(HUGE.CLASSIFICATION_DEADLINE,'DD/MM/RRRR hh12:mi') <= trunc(SYSDATE)  THEN 'DELAYED'
            WHEN HUGE.CURRENT_PHASES = 'Feasibility'  and to_date(HUGE.FEASIBILITY_DEADLINE,'DD/MM/RRRR hh12:mi') <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
            WHEN HUGE.CURRENT_PHASES = 'Classification'   and to_date(HUGE.CLASSIFICATION_DEADLINE,'DD/MM/RRRR hh12:mi') >= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'OK'
            WHEN HUGE.CURRENT_PHASES = 'Feasibility'  and to_date(HUGE.FEASIBILITY_DEADLINE,'DD/MM/RRRR hh12:mi') >= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'OK'                        
END
STATE
 from 
(select
 b.PRBID,b.CREATIONDATE CREATION_DATE,b.PHASES CURRENT_PHASES,
 CASE
             WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null THEN 'Feasibility'
             WHEN phases = 'Feasibility' and CreationDate is not null THEN 'Completed'
END
NEXT_PHASES,
CASE
            WHEN b.phases = 'Classification' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is not null THEN to_char(b.creationdate + 5 + floor(((a.unholddate-a.holddate)*24*60*60)/3600)/24,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
            WHEN b.phases = 'Classification' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is null THEN 'HOLD'
           ELSE to_char(creationdate+5,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
END
CLASSIFICATION_DEADLINE,
CASE
            WHEN b.phases = 'Feasibility' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is not null THEN to_char(b.creationdate + 5 + floor(((a.unholddate-a.holddate)*24*60*60)/3600)/24,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
            WHEN b.phases = 'Feasibility' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is null THEN 'HOLD'
            ELSE to_char(creationdate+10,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
END
FEASIBILITY_DEADLINE
from PRB_PHASES b, PRB_HOLD_TIME a
where a.PRBid = b.PRBid
union
select
b.PRBID,b.CREATIONDATE CREATION_DATE,b.PHASES CURRENT_PHASES,
 CASE
             WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null THEN 'Feasibility'
             WHEN phases = 'Feasibility' and CreationDate is not null THEN 'Completed'
END
NEXT_PHASES,
CASE
            WHEN b.phases = 'Classification' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is not null THEN to_char(b.creationdate + 5 + floor(((a.unholddate-a.holddate)*24*60*60)/3600)/24,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
            WHEN b.phases = 'Classification' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is null THEN 'HOLD'
           ELSE to_char(creationdate+5,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
END
CLASSIFICATION_DEADLINE,
CASE
            WHEN b.phases = 'Feasibility' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is not null THEN to_char(b.creationdate + 5 + floor(((a.unholddate-a.holddate)*24*60*60)/3600)/24,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
            WHEN b.phases = 'Feasibility' and b.INSERTIONDATE is not null and b.Priority = 1 and b.Complexity = 'minor' and a.holddate is not null and a.unholddate is null THEN 'HOLD'
                    ELSE to_char(creationdate+10,'dd/mm/rrrr hh12:mi')
END
FEASIBILITY_DEADLINE
from PRB_PHASES b,PRB_HOLD_TIME a
where a.PRBid <> b.PRBid)  HUGE
```

Comment: please reformat your submission it is not readable in its current format.

Comment: If you could provide a simplified example showing the logic you need, it would be easier.

Comment: Aleksej, e.g. PRBID 0001 in Current phase = Classification and Classification deadline is 29/1/2016 but i put it on hold status for 2 days the Classification deadline must be 2/2/2016 instead  31/1/2016

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need a way to count the days, excluding weekend, in an interval of dates, you may try something like this:

```
SELECT SUM( DECODE( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL - 1, 'd'), 
                  '6', 0,
                  '7', 0, 
                       1
                  )
           )
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY TO_DATE('01-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL <= TO_DATE('31-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
  ORDER BY LEVEL
```

This will evaluate the number of days between 01/01/2016 and 31/01/2016, without counting saturdays and sundays

Comment: looks good but how i can use it in my query sorry for the question but im newbie all this query is made after many hours of googling

Answer (score 0):

I have not read your entire submission but to remove weekends from a calculation you can use the following:

```
select  sum(end_dt - start_dt) * 24 * 60 work_minutes
      into  v_return
      from  t
      where trunc(start_dt) - trunc(start_dt,'iw') < 5; -- exclude weekends
RETURN v_return;
```

This is taken from a larger query that is used to calculate the working_minutes between 2 date values. The important part for you is the WHERE clause, this subtracts weekends from the calculation, it could probably be amended to fir your needs however the format of you question means it is difficult to establish what you require exactly.